# Find targets position after isotope positioning

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry

I'm using David Desandros [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) for a new site, but now it seems I'm unable to find each elements position using jquery. Specifically I'm trying to attach a tooltip on hover, but generally I'd like to know how to get the position() of each anchor after Isotope has formatted them.

As of now each element displays a '0' for left, margin-left, position().left, and every other positioning property I could think of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See Isotope docs for [itemPositionDataEnabled](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#itempositiondataenabled)

```
$('#container').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element',
  itemPositionDataEnabled: true
})
// log position of each item
.find('.element').each(function(){
  var position = $(this).data('isotope-item-position');
  console.log('item position is x: ' + position.x + ', y: ' + position.y  );
});
```

Comment: A bastion of knowledge, thanks for clearing this up and creating such a great tool.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, after viewing the the source code in one of [Isotope's demos](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/filtering.html) in Firebug, I found that the position is being calculated via:

```
-moz-transform: translate(#px, #px)
```

and

```
-webkit-transform: translate(#px, #px)
```

I am not sure what is being used for other browsers such as IE, but you should be able to access their position that way.