# Subtracting pixels from TOP and LEFT values in a jQuery script

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry, tweak

I'd like to tweak this Masonry plugin to always subtract 1 pixel from the TOP and LEFT css values on each "brick."

```
(function(a, b, c) {
    "use strict";
    var d = b.event,
        e;
    d.special.smartresize = {
        setup: function() {
            b(this).bind("resize", d.special.smartresize.handler)
        },
        teardown: function() {
            b(this).unbind("resize", d.special.smartresize.handler)
        },
        handler: function(a, b) {
            var c = this,
                d = arguments;
            a.type = "smartresize", e && clearTimeout(e), e = setTimeout(function() {
                jQuery.event.handle.apply(c, d)
            }, b === "execAsap" ? 0 : 100)
        }
    }, b.fn.smartresize = function(a) {
        return a ? this.bind("smartresize", a) : this.trigger("smartresize", ["execAsap"])
    }, b.Mason = function(a, c) {
        this.element = b(c), this._create(a), this._init()
    }, b.Mason.settings = {
        isResizable: !0,
        isAnimated: !1,
        animationOptions: {
            queue: !1,
            duration: 500
        },
        gutterWidth: 0,
        isRTL: !1,
        isFitWidth: !1,
        containerStyle: {
            position: "relative"
        }
    }, b.Mason.prototype = {
        _filterFindBricks: function(a) {
            var b = this.options.brickSelector;
            return b ? a.filter(b).add(a.find(b)) : a
        },
        _getBricks: function(a) {
            var b = this._filterFindBricks(a).css({
                position: "absolute"
            });
            return b
        },
        _create: function(c) {
            this.options = b.extend(!0, {}, b.Mason.settings, c), this.styleQueue = [];
            var d = this.element[0].style;
            this.originalStyle = {
                height: d.height || ""
            };
            var e = this.options.containerStyle;
            for (var f in e) this.originalStyle[f] = d[f] || "";
            this.element.css(e), this.horizontalDirection = this.options.isRTL ? "right" : "left", this.offset = {
                x: parseInt(this.element.css("padding-" + this.horizontalDirection), 10),
                y: parseInt(this.element.css("padding-top"), 10)
            }, this.isFluid = this.options.columnWidth && typeof this.options.columnWidth == "function";
            var g = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                g.element.addClass("masonry")
            }, 0), this.options.isResizable && b(a).bind("smartresize.masonry", function() {
                g.resize()
            }), this.reloadItems()
        },
        _init: function(a) {
            this._getColumns(), this._reLayout(a)
        },
        option: function(a, c) {
            b.isPlainObject(a) && (this.options = b.extend(!0, this.options, a))
        },
        layout: function(a, b) {
            for (var c = 0, d = a.length; c < d; c++) this._placeBrick(a[c]);
            var e = {};
            e.height = Math.max.apply(Math, this.colYs);
            if (this.options.isFitWidth) {
                var f = 0;
                c = this.cols;
                while (--c) {
                    if (this.colYs[c] !== 0) break;
                    f++
                }
                e.width = (this.cols - f) * this.columnWidth - this.options.gutterWidth
            }
            this.styleQueue.push({
                $el: this.element,
                style: e
            });
            var g = this.isLaidOut ? this.options.isAnimated ? "animate" : "css" : "css",
                h = this.options.animationOptions,
                i;
            for (c = 0, d = this.styleQueue.length; c < d; c++) i = this.styleQueue[c], i.$el[g](i.style, h);
            this.styleQueue = [], b && b.call(a), this.isLaidOut = !0
        },
        _getColumns: function() {
            var a = this.options.isFitWidth ? this.element.parent() : this.element,
                b = a.width();
            this.columnWidth = this.isFluid ? this.options.columnWidth(b) : this.options.columnWidth || this.$bricks.outerWidth(!0) || b, this.columnWidth += this.options.gutterWidth, this.cols = Math.floor((b + this.options.gutterWidth) / this.columnWidth), this.cols = Math.max(this.cols, 1)
        },
        _placeBrick: function(a) {
            var c = b(a),
                d, e, f, g, h;
            d = Math.ceil(c.outerWidth(!0) / (this.columnWidth + this.options.gutterWidth)), d = Math.min(d, this.cols);
            if (d === 1) f = this.colYs;
            else {
                e = this.cols + 1 - d, f = [];
                for (h = 0; h < e; h++) g = this.colYs.slice(h, h + d), f[h] = Math.max.apply(Math, g)
            }
            var i = Math.min.apply(Math, f),
                j = 0;
            for (var k = 0, l = f.length; k < l; k++) if (f[k] === i) {
                j = k;
                break
            }
            var m = {
                top: i + this.offset.y
            };
            m[this.horizontalDirection] = this.columnWidth * j + this.offset.x, this.styleQueue.push({
                $el: c,
                style: m
            });
            var n = i + c.outerHeight(!0),
                o = this.cols + 1 - l;
            for (k = 0; k < o; k++) this.colYs[j + k] = n
        },
        resize: function() {
            var a = this.cols;
            this._getColumns(), (this.isFluid || this.cols !== a) && this._reLayout()
        },
        _reLayout: function(a) {
            var b = this.cols;
            this.colYs = [];
            while (b--) this.colYs.push(0);
            this.layout(this.$bricks, a)
        },
        reloadItems: function() {
            this.$bricks = this._getBricks(this.element.children())
        },
        reload: function(a) {
            this.reloadItems(), this._init(a)
        },
        appended: function(a, b, c) {
            if (b) {
                this._filterFindBricks(a).css({
                    top: this.element.height()
                });
                var d = this;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    d._appended(a, c)
                }, 1)
            } else this._appended(a, c)
        },
        _appended: function(a, b) {
            var c = this._getBricks(a);
            this.$bricks = this.$bricks.add(c), this.layout(c, b)
        },
        remove: function(a) {
            this.$bricks = this.$bricks.not(a), a.remove()
        },
        destroy: function() {
            this.$bricks.removeClass("masonry-brick").each(function() {
                this.style.position = "", this.style.top = "", this.style.left = ""
            });
            var c = this.element[0].style;
            for (var d in this.originalStyle) c[d] = this.originalStyle[d];
            this.element.unbind(".masonry").removeClass("masonry").removeData("masonry"), b(a).unbind(".masonry")
        }
    }, b.fn.imagesLoaded = function(a) {
        function i(a) {
            var c = a.target;
            c.src !== f && b.inArray(c, g) === -1 && (g.push(c), --e <= 0 && (setTimeout(h), d.unbind(".imagesLoaded", i)))
        }
        function h() {
            a.call(c, d)
        }
        var c = this,
            d = c.find("img").add(c.filter("img")),
            e = d.length,
            f = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==",
            g = [];
        e || h(), d.bind("load.imagesLoaded error.imagesLoaded", i).each(function() {
            var a = this.src;
            this.src = f, this.src = a
        });
        return c
    };
    var f = function(b) {
        a.console && a.console.error(b)
    };
    b.fn.masonry = function(a) {
        if (typeof a == "string") {
            var c = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
            this.each(function() {
                var d = b.data(this, "masonry");
                if (!d) f("cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization; attempted to call method '" + a + "'");
                else {
                    if (!b.isFunction(d[a]) || a.charAt(0) === "_") {
                        f("no such method '" + a + "' for masonry instance");
                        return
                    }
                    d[a].apply(d, c)
                }
            })
        } else this.each(function() {
            var c = b.data(this, "masonry");
            c ? (c.option(a || {}), c._init()) : b.data(this, "masonry", new b.Mason(a, this))
        });
        return this
    }
})(window, jQuery);​
```

Comment: You could have linked to the github repository rather than pasting uncommented code. But, why would you want to subtract one pixel from the top left?

Comment: Well, it's an edited version of the code. I'm trying to subtract 1px from the Top and Left values of the "brick," which has a 1px border. By subtracting those pixels, my grid will have a consistent 1px border throughout. I know it's possible to use a negative margin, but that was causing the contents of the bricks to act wonky.

Comment: If done right, you can surely have 1px lines around your Masonry elements without hacking DeSandro's code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using negative margin

```
margin: -1px -1px 0 0;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/nJhVr/3/

Answer (score 0):

1px line around each Masonry element [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nJhVr/1/).

**UPDATE** You can have a 1px line only on the top and left [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/nJhVr/2/), but then Masonry elements on the right and bottom won't have a line on them at all. You could use Isotope instead, test for [each item's position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6255657/963514) to programmatically turn on the missing 1px line on the right and bottom for items on the right and the bottom of your #container.

Comment: Ah, perfect example! See, I'm going for a 1px border throughout. In your fiddle, you'll notice that all interior borders are 2px, because they're shared. I'd like to use Top and Left to create the overlap, as opposed to a negative margin.